# How to lock different objects with different methods?

Tags: java, multithreading

I got 2 threads and I want to run Student object's different methods with these threads. Problem is when I run this code t2 thread waits for t1 to complete synchronized block.

Why It is waiting for t1 to complete? How can I lock different objects with different methods without blocking each other?

Here is main method;

```
Student student = new Student();
Thread t1 = new Thread(() -> {
    try {
        student.addA();
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
});

Thread t2 = new Thread(() -> {
    try {
        student.addB();
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
});

t1.start();
t2.start();
```

Here is Student class;

```
public class Student {

  private Integer a = 0;
  private Integer b = 0;

  public void addA() throws InterruptedException{
      System.out.println("addA start");
      synchronized(a){
          System.out.println("addA sync start");
          a++;
          Thread.sleep(5000);
      }
      System.out.println("addA end");
  }

  public void addB() throws InterruptedException{
      System.out.println("addB start");
      synchronized(b){
          System.out.println("addB sync start");
          b++;
          Thread.sleep(5000);
      }
      System.out.println("addB end");
  }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This:

```
private Integer a = 0;
private Integer b = 0;
```

is actually the same as this:

```
private Integer a = Integer.valueOf(0);
private Integer b = Integer.valueOf(0);
```

and [the result of `Integer.valueOf(0)` is cached](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf-int-), so you're actually synchronizing on the same object.

You can use `new Integer(0)` to get different `Integer` instances.

But this is just kicking the problem one iteration down the road:

```
a++;
```

is actually:

```
a = Integer.valueOf(a.intValue() + 1);
```

so you can potentially run into the same problem again, at least until `a`'s value exceeds the range of values cached by the `Integer.valueOf` method (at least 127, but implementation dependent).

You can apply the same trick:

```
a = new Integer(a.intValue() + 1);
```

**However**, synchronizing on a mutable reference is a pretty bad idea, because as soon as this line has been executed, another thread can enter that synchronized block. (Not ones that were already blocked from entering it, but any thread reaching the `synchronized` afterwards).

Instead, you should create a separate lock object for each of `a` and `b`:

```
private final Object aLock = new Object();
private final Object bLock = new Object();
```

and synchronize on *these* instead of `a` and `b` correspondingly.